# Best way to pass data into plugin objects

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I often have the problem that I have different plugins that all essentially perform the same task, but all in a different way. So each plugin needs different kinds of parameters, but how to pass them?

```
IMySpecificTask plugin = PluginResolver.Resolve(typeof(IMySpecificTask));
```

Each implementation of `IMySpecificTask` needs different objects of my domain which it needs to access.
I could certainly use a service locator/singleton pattern to get the information which I need but isn't there a cleaner way?

Another way I could think of but which also seem fishy to me is something like this:

```
if (plugin is INeedsServiceA a)
    a.SetServiceA(myserviceA);
if (plugin is INeedsServiceB b)
    b.SetServiceB(myserviceB);
...
```